# Service Reference for a webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, service-reference

I have a vs.net solution with 2 web projects
WebApp1: has 1 form called Default.aspx
WebApp2: has 1 webservice called webservice1

I right clicked on WebApp1 and clicked "Add Service Reference" and added a reference to WebApp2.Webservice1, its called wsref1. Now the problem I am facing is that in default.aspx when I try to add a servicereference in script manager to this webservice, it just doesnt work.

Is it possible to references webservices declared in another web application project that is part of the same solution?

Comment: is it throwing any exception? If yes, what is that? Try to use any HTTP tracing tool to see what is happening.

Comment: basically the issue is that I dont know how to add this service as a reference to the scriptmanager in default.aspx. there is no .svc file that all samples on net shows ie this code doesnt work

sub page_load()
ScriptManager1.Services.add(new ServiceReference("what do I put in here"))
end sub

the namespace of service is WebApp2.WebService1, but that does not work